# AsyncTask behavior confusion

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this project:

Im trying to undestand where is the problem and how can be solved, but a this simply point I really dont know where is the problem.
I have a button and a TextView.
When the button is clicked this procedure is called:

```
android:onClick="pulsaboton"
```

And the TextView show me the output.

This is Main_Activity.java

```
package com.example.pruebasonidos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public String cadena1="", cadena2="";
public TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview01);
}
public class generamusica extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        tv.setText(tv.getText().toString()+"Pre Execute");  
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String...strings) {

        String cadena=strings[0];
        tv.setText(tv.getText().toString()+cadena); 
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer bytes){
        tv.setText(tv.getText().toString()+"Post Execute"); 
    }

}
public void pulsaboton(View v) {
cadena1="123"; cadena2="111";
tv.setText("");
new generamusica().execute(cadena1);
new generamusica().execute(cadena2);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

When pulsaboton is clicked, textview1 display this:

```
PreExecutePreExecute123111PostExecutePostExecute
```

I want this output:

```
PreExecute123PostExecutePreExecute111PostExecute
```

What is the error????

Comment: running the above on pre honeycomb api version?

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: INTERFACE MODIFICATION EXECUTED OUTSIDE OF UI THREAD!

```
protected Integer doInBackground(String...strings) {
    ...
    tv.setText(tv.getText().toString()+cadena); 
    ...
}
```

Why do you think `AsyncTask` exposes `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute`? Couldn't you just do all of your interface work in `doInBackground`, before and after your async code?

In Android, the UI needs to be accessed from the main thread, the **foreground** thread; which `doInBackground` is **not** run in.

If you need to post updates to your UI **during** the execution of an `AsyncTask`, use the `publishProgress` mechanism.

**Edit:** "properly" accesing the interface is a lot more complex that just using `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute`. See [this blog post](http://blogactivity.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/proper-use-of-asynctask/). Maybe you should try the `Loader` API, it's less troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. **Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.**.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You are updating ui on the background thread which is not possible. You need to update ui on the ui thread

In doInBackground()

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
             {
              public void run() 
              {       
                   String cadena=strings[0];
                   tv.setText(tv.getText().toString()+cadena); ;
             }
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

For your required output Call these two lines in `onPostExecute`,

```
 cadena2="111";
    new generamusica().execute(cadena2);
```

And dont try to update the UI in background thread.

See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008663/792232) for more info