# Storing images into sdcard?

Tags: android

I captured Screen using bellow code and then it stored in sdcard and go to another activity.but when i navigate to another activity is very slow.how can i solve it?
Please can anyone help me?

```
  View v1 = view.getRootView();    
   v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);    
bitmapBcfhForm3 = v1.getDrawingCache();    
File imagesFolder = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Signatures");

            imagesFolder.mkdirs();    
            String fileName = "bitmapBcfhForm3"+AppointmentDetails.getPatientId+".png";
            File out = new File(imagesFolder,fileName);
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream1 = new FileOutputStream(out);
            bitmapBcfhForm3.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream1); 
            mFileOutStream1.flush();
            mFileOutStream1.close();
            }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.v("log_tag", e.toString()); 
                }   
         startActivity(new intent(A.this.B.classs));
```

Answer (score 0):

you are taking screen-shot and saving it to ExternalStorage, this process will block your UI Thread, so try to do that screen-shot and saving functionality in saparate worker thread; for this you may use simple Thread object, or else user AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to perform Capturing and saving in task in another thread. For that best option is `AsycTask`

Check this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008663/792232), Search and learn Asynctask working.

Happy coding :)